# html5 video tag not working when i published to iis server

Tags: asp.net, html, iis, iis-7

I have built a asp.net site with c# code behind. Everything works when i publish via VS to my server which uses IIS7 except my video tag running a mp4 video.

It works when i run it locally but not when published to server, just a black box where it should be.

The video src is relative path and the video is included in the solution and i see it is in the web servers folder. My target browser is chrome but ideally i dont want it limited to this - at present it fails on chrome and ie, havnt checked any others.

my video tag

```
<table align="center" style="width:100%;height:100%">
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="center">
            <video id="splashVideo" runat="server" width="50%" height="50%" autoplay>
                <source src="splash.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As this is not using anythng other than html i havnt included any other ocde except below but let me know if anything else is pertinent, this may probably be a permissions issue or iss issue.

HTML head and meta tags

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="mysite.aspx.cs" Inherits="img_mysite" %>
<%@ Register assembly="mysiteCustomButton" namespace="mysiteCustomButton" tagprefix="cc1" %>


<link href="mysite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>my site</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>
```

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it. IIS5 issue - needed to add new MIME type to my IIS server mySite setup.

IIS->->MIME Types->Confirm no entry for the video file type->add "mp4"/"video/m4"